# Composite Hash of Ordered List

Tags: algorithm, hash

Suppose I have an ordered list of n objects (x1, x2, ..., xn) of some type (eg variable length binary data files).

Each of these objects has been secure hashed (eg SHA1) to produce an m-bit hash code (h1, h2, ..., hn)

I now wish to combine these hash codes into a composite code that uniquely and securely (ignoring negligble collision probability) identifies the ordered list.

(Assume that the objects are large and reading their actual data again is not an option)

One naive and incorrect way to do this would be to XOR the hash codes together.  This has the undesirable property that (x1, x2) would have the same composite code as (x2, x1).

By what algorithm can I combine the hash codes to have the desired properties?

Comment: Hmmm... Interesting!  Can you just hash the concatenation of their hashes with the initial hash function?

Answer (score 2):

For consistency and security reasons, I would combine the individual hashes of the list items by applying SHA-1 to  the concatenations of the individuals SHA-1 hashes.

Answer (score 1):

Possible you can use the same algorithm as in java for list hashes, this is example for 32-bit hash code

```
int hashCode = 0;
for(Element e:list) {
   hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
}
```

For multilayer you can use another prime number. I hope you get the main idea of this algorithm and can apply to arbitrary m-bit hash codes.